# Can I put multiple jRecorder elements on one page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have been trying to find a plugin that would allow users on my site to record a voice clip, after searching for a while I ended up with [jRecorder](http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder/).  However the issue with this is that I need to have multiple jRecorder instances on a single page, and they must each write to a separate file.

I have been unable to find how to do this and was wondering if anyone has had success implementing this.

Comment: where you able to do this?

Comment: No I wasn't, however I found that [Wami Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/) did what I needed to, it doesn't require separate instances as the location that the audio is sent to is defined in the `record(url)` function. so you essentially have one recorder instance and each button sends to a different url if you want.